# Is there a way to reuse a CSS style but with different background images?

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a website project and I am trying to use the same `<style>` for a number of `<a>` but I want to set a different background image for all of them while preserving the `<style>` functionality. I tried with `nth-child` selectors but it does not preserve the functions of the CSS.

**CSS**

```
  #par .article-image:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;  
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(./images/try1.jpg);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

#par .article-image:hover:before {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%) blur(2px);
  filter: grayscale(50%) blur(2px);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

    #par .article-image:before a:nth-child(2){ 
    background-image: url(./images/try2.jpg) ;
    }
    #par .article-image:before a:nth-child(3){  
    background-image: url(./images/try3.jpg) ;
    }
    #par .article-image:before a:nth-child(4){ 
    background-image: url(./images/try4.jpg) ;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="par" class="expanded button-group hollow no-gaps parent" style="height:500px" >
            <a class="large button th article-image">1 
       <div class="middle"> <div><img src="./images/1.jpg" /></div> </div> </a>
            <a class="large button th article-image">2 
       <div class="middle"> <div><img src="./images/2.jpg" /></div> </div> </a>         
            <a class="large button th article-image">3
       <div class="middle"> <div><img src="./images/3.jpg" /></div> </div> </a>
            <a class="large button th article-image>4
       <div class="middle"> <div><img src="./images/4.jpg" /></div> </div> </a>
          </div>

</body>
```

**P.s** I tried using `a:nth-child(1..2..3..4)` but it did not work as it did not use the style functionality. Basically I want to set different background images that will be applied on `<a>` while applying the same style for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your css selector.
You need to use :nth-child on the same div (`.article-image`). Like this.

```css
 #par .article-image:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;  
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(./images/try1.jpg);
  filter: grayscale(0) blur(0);
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
#par .article-image:nth-child(2):before{ 
  background-image: url(./images/try2.jpg) ;
}
#par .article-image:nth-child(3):before{  
  background-image: url(./images/try3.jpg) ;
  }
#par .article-image:nth-child(4):before{ 
  background-image: url(./images/try4.jpg) ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I searched everywhere but no one seemed to have answered a case like this. I guess I still have more to learn about `nth-child`. Cheers and have a good one!

Comment: Great, it helped. In case you liked the answer you can always up vote it ;) @Mechev